# Changing External Crystal of ATMEGA2560

Tags: avr, atmega

In new project I'm working on I changed 8MHz external crystal of ATMEGA2560 to 16MHz Now UART and I2C are not working. What all changes needs to be done to make this work?

Comment: Didn't you expect that changing the oscillator frequency might change other timing features. Obviously something needs to be divided by 2. Read the datasheet section "System Clock and Clock Options".

Comment: @Nedd I am looking into the same.

Comment: It depends what the problem is. Are you sure the MCU or crystal is even working at all? What is supply voltage for MCU, 3.3V or 5V or something else? Which exact MCU model it is, 2560V or non-V? Which MCU revision it is?